# how to pass custom parameter through submit button in mvc4

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

Hello everyone i am creating a login page using mvc4 wherein the login credentials are fetched from the database. In the database the relevant table contains 3 columns namely: **userid**, **password** and **partnerid**. When the user enters his credentials and clicks submit button, and if the login is successful, he is taken to a page whose address is like this :

```
http://localhost:58361/Home?result1=true
```

this is my submit button code:

```
<input type="submit" value="Login" class="login_button" onclick="return validateLoginPage()" />
```

here validateLoginPage is a js function which checks whether any input fields are not left blank.

My requirement is that on click of submit button the address of the page to which the user is redirected be shown like this:

```
http://localhost:58361/Home?result1=true?partnerid='somevalue'
```

**The partnerid value is taken from the database and stored in a ViewData**

how to achieve this? Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

This is the actionresult for the submit button

```
    public ActionResult Index(LoginModel model,string res)
    {
        LoginUser = model.Userid;
        LoginPassword = model.Password;
        verify(LoginUser, LoginPassword);
        res = result;
        if (res == "true")
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { result1 = result });
        }
        else
        {
            ViewData["alert"] = "The Login Credentials are Incorrect";
            return View();
        }
    }
```

The **verify** method verifies with the database whether the login credentials are correct or not and returns the string value **"result"** as true or false

Comment: can you post action result that does the validation and builds http://localhost:58361/Home?result1=true# link

Comment: To clarify, you want the user to end up at the mentioned URL after submitting their credentials and having been authenticated? And the place/time where you will get the partnerid to use is after authentication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to submit a form that directs user to

```
Home?result1=true?partnerid='somevalue'
```

I interpret that as going to Home Controller with null action (defaulting to Index) and passing result1=true always, and partnerid from ViewData

```
    @using(Html.BeginForm(null, "Home", FormMethod.Get, 
new { result1=true, partnerid='@(ViewData["somevalue"])' })) //for query string
```

**Warning:** As Karthik has consderately pointed out, this code is untested. It's more to demonstrate the point:

Comment: @DaveA, It could be better to use a POST instead of GET, if the data is sensitive.

Comment: @Murali, I agree in general principal and best practice. In this case I'm trying to respond to OP without bias. Which means querystring (Get). But I agree with your point.

Comment: +1, I like this way of posting a data using Form. Before i used to have a hidden variable :(

Comment: @Murali, I believe varied ways for varied needs ;)

Comment: Your approach reduces a additional DOM element & response size too :)

Comment: @DaveA, thanks 4 ur response...if i use ur method, the validation for login credentials is not happening.Even if i give wrong credentials it is accepting and logging into the page.I have given the code for the actionresult also..maybe that will help in understanding my problem. Thanks again

Comment: @nitinvertigo, I see, you need to model-bind. does you require a query string approach (get) or can this be a post?

Comment: @DaveA actually the login credentials are model-bound. The approach can be anything.

Comment: then I'd say attempt a post. I was thinking using Get b/c of the querystring. But you can combine the 2. And I think you need to post to Model bind

Comment: so attempt the same using FormMethod.Post

Answer (score 0):

Create an hidden input holding your value like this:

```
<input type="hidden" value="XXX" name="refNameHere" />
```

Comment: I added the name attribute that i forgot. Also make sure your form method is set to GET. If i understand your question right, that should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that I've understood your question correctly and your controller method for Home Index looks something like this

```
public ActionResult Index(int partnerid)
{
    ViewBag.PartnerId = partnerid;
    return View();
}
```

You should be fine with doing this in your login method

```
public ActionResult Login()
{
    // Authentication stuff goes here
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { partnerid = 1 });
}
```

Since you added the code for the action that handles the login that simplifies my edit.
All you would have to do would be to get the partnerid from your data source, put it in a string and wrap it in '' and then change

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { result1 = result });
```

to

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { result1 = result, partnerid = partnerId });
```

then you would have to add an Index action on your HomeController to take string parameters named result1 and partnerid and everything should work

Comment: I see what you are going for. I feel it can be improved to better meet the OP question. If you care to improve it, I would be happy to vote it up.

Comment: missed this. big improvement, not sure it exactly meets OP, but neither does mine. keep workin at it. @pmacnaughton

Comment: I have a feeling that the title might be somewhat misleading and what is actually requested if for a user to end up at the mentioned URL after authentication, and that the partnerid can only be gotten after authentication as well.